# How well does the Visual C++ 2008/2010 compiler optimize?

Tags: c++, optimization, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-optimization

Im just wondering how good the MSVC++ Compiler can optimize code(with Code examples) or what he can't optimize and why.

For example i used the SSE-intrinsics with something like this(var is an __m128 value)(it was for an frustrum-culling test):

```
if( var.m128_f32[0] > 0.0f && var.m128_f32[1] > 0.0f && var.m128_f32[2] > 0.0f && var.m128_f32[3] > 0.0f ) {
    ...
}
```

As i took a look at the asm-output i saw that it did compile to an ugly very jumpy version (and i know that the CPU's just hate tight jumps) and i know also that i can optimize it with the SSE4.1 PTEST instruction, but why did the compiler not do it(even if the compiler writers defined the PTEST intrinsic, so they knew the instruction)?

What optimizations can't it do too (until now).

Does this imply that im with the todays technology forced to use intrinsics and inline ASM and linked ASM functions and will compilers ever find such things(i don't think so)?

Where can i read more about how good the MSVC++ compiler optimizes?

*(Edit 1):*
I used the SSE2 switch and FP:fast switch

Comment: sorry, pet peeve... it's  'How WELL does the ...'

Comment: @Lucas Well job on that correction.

Comment: The best way to find the answer to this is to compare the code it emits to the code emitted by other compilers (e.g., Intel C++, g++, etc.)

Comment: Depending on what you are actually doing it might be more efficient to use the optimized code others have written, e.g. by using Intels IPP.

Comment: @ Tyler I did correct it pretty good, didn't I :)

Comment: Out of interest, what compiler optimisation switches are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default for the compiler is set to generate code that wil run on a 'lowest common denominator' CPU - ie one without SSE 4.1 instructions.

You can change that by targetting later CPUs only in the build options.

That said, the MS compiler is traditionally 'not the best' when it comes to [SSE optimisation](http://www.liranuna.com/sse-intrinsics-optimizations-in-popular-compilers/). I'm not even sure if it supports SSE 4 at all. That link gives good credit to GCC for SSE optimisation:

> As a side note about GCC’s near
>   perfection in code generation – I was
>   quite surprised seeing it surpass even
>   Intel’s own compiler

Perhaps you need to change compiler!

Comment: ok, i had forget to mention that i setted it to SSE2, maybe there need to be a SSE4.1 switch ;). And thx for the GCC hint, ill check it out soon and try to squeeze it out :P

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try Intel's ICC compiler - in my experience it generates a lot better code than Visual C++, especially for SSE code. You can get a free 30 day evaluation license from intel.com.

Comment: It's also caught a lot of flak for generating needlessly inefficient code for AMD cpus

Comment: @jalf: I guess that's a moot point, since SSE on AMD CPUs is pretty much useless - you probably want to use Intel CPUs if you're doing serious SIMD work.

Comment: most people write software that has to run on multiple CPU's. Also, I'm not really sure what your problem with AMD's SSE performance is. I'm not aware of any significant limitations on AMD CPU's. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @jalf: AMD still has no support for SSSE3, and its SSE implementation is still 64 bits under the hood (like on pre "Core" Intel CPUs - it takes two clocks to perform a 128 bit operation) so there is a severe performance limitation compared to current generation Intel CPUs which have SSSE3 and full 128 bit execution units.

Comment: -1: This is not an answer, it is marketing without any backup of claims.

Comment: @phresnel: I have no connection with Intel or Microsoft - my answer above is based on extensive benchmarking of C/C++ code, both scalar and SIMD, over a number of years. Feel free to disagree with my conclusions, but there is no need for unfounded accusations of "marketing".

Comment: @Paul R: I did not really assume that you are from Intel, I just don't think that this is a good answer before the standards of Stack Overflow. I'll remove my -1, even though I think you should mention those benchmarks, ideally with some code or so.

Comment: @unixman83: no - AMD have been somewhat irrelevant when it comes to HPC for quite a few years now.

Answer (score 1):

You can activate asm view of the compiled code and see yourself what is generated.

Comment: i did it (well, i have written it this way, PTEST is an asm instruction), but the question was just why the compiler didn't use this optimization... maybe because the MSVC++ guys didn't thought about such an use/abuse...

Answer (score 0):

Check the presentation at http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3674

Summary: Compilers generally do lots of amazing tricks now, even things that doesn't seem to be generally related to imperative programming, like tail-call optimization. MSVC++ is not the best, still it seems pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Ïf-statements generate conditional jumps unless you can utilize conditional moves but that is more likely something done in hand-written assembly. There are rules that govern the CPU's conditional jump assumptions (branch prediction) such that the penalty of a conditional jump which behaves along the rules is acceptable. Then there is out-of-order execution to additionally complicate things :). The bottom line is that if your code is straight-forward the jumps which eventually occur won't mess up performance. You might check out Agner Fog's [optimization pages](http://www.agner.org/optimize/).

A non-debug compilation of your C-code specifically should generate four conditional jumps. The logical ands (&&) and parentheses usage will result in a left-to-right testing so one C optimization could be to test the f32 that is most likely to be >0.0f first (if such a probability can be determined). You have five possible execution variants: test1 true branch taken (t1tbt), test1 false no branch (t1fnb) test2 true branch taken (t2tbt), etc giving the following possible sequences

```
t1tbt                      ; var.m128_f32[0] <= 0.0f
t1fnb t2tbt                ; var.m128_f32[0] >  0.0f, var.m128_f32[1] <= 0.0f
t1fnb t2fnb t3tbt          ; var.m128_f32[0] >  0.0f, var.m128_f32[1] >  0.0f,
                           ; var.m128_f32[2] <= 0.0f
t1fnb t2fnb t3fnb t4tbt    ; var.m128_f32[0] >  0.0f, var.m128_f32[1] >  0.0f,
                           ; var.m128_f32[2] >  0.0f, var.m128_f32[3] <= 0.0f
t1fnb t2fnb t3fnb t4fnb    ; var.m128_f32[0] >  0.0f, var.m128_f32[1] >  0.0f
                           ; var.m128_f32[2] >  0.0f, var.m128_f32[3] >  0.0f
```

Only a taken branch will result in a pipelining disruption and branch prediction will minimize the disruption as much as possible.

Assuming floats are expensive to test (they are), if var is a union and you are well-versed in floating-point ins and outs you might consider doing integer testing on the overlapping types. For example the stored value 1.0f occupies four bytes stored as 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x3f (x86/little-endian). Reading this value as a long integer will give 0x3f800000 or +1065353216. 0.0f is 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 or 0x00000000 (long). Negative float values have exactly the same format as positive with the exception that the highest bit is set (0x80000000).